# Design pattern for extending Android's activities?

Tags: android, design-patterns

While programming on Android, I end up writing a parent activity which is extended by several others. A bit like `ListActivity`. My parent activity extends `Activity`. if I intend to use a `Map` or a `List`, I can't use my parent activity as superclass - the child activity can only extend one activity obviously. As such I end up writing my parent activities with the same logic for `Activity`, `ListActivity`, `MapActivity` and so forth.

What am I looking for is some sort of trait functionality/design pattern which would help in this case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I really dislike `ListActivity`, `MapActivity` etc. Basically they are activities which simply add a single view element at the cost of some flexibility. By adding a `MapView` or `ListView` to your XML appropriately, you end up with the same thing which can extend an `Activity` derived superclass directly. So just don't use any of those SomethingActivity classes for the most part.

Comment: It is not only adding a view. You have the map lifecycle/cursor handler and so forth depending on which activity you use. The benefits might not balance the inflexibility but some code is definitely gained by using predisposed classes.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up having a base `MyAbstractActivity extends Activity` that incorporates shared logic and a `MyAbstractListActivity extends MyAbstractActivity` that mimics `ListActivity` (inflates `layout.R.id.list`, `layout.R.id.empty`, etc.; not much going on there).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) with all the shared functionality. This enables me to have all the shared functionality in one single class for all the different activities.
All my activities extend their special activity and then implement a common interface. The problem with this approach is that I need to implement all the methods defined in the interface and  call the matching method in the delegate object. This code at the moment amounts to 30 duplicate lines of code and I think that is not that much of a problem.